# broken pendrive. gui software is crashing. any ideas for commands ? it only seems for not lagging

Tags: hardware, parted

yes. problem is :

- when i connect his pendrive PC automatically slow down
- after trying to change something in gparted, program immediately lags and i need to force close
- systems I'm using - ubuntu 20.10 with gnome 3.38.3 ; windows 10 (but there I can do nothing) , [this system I made](https://github.com/users/hacknorris-notyetbanned/projects/4) .

  Edit: now i use only pure linux mint from live boot, window$ have bluescreen, ubuntu i’ve deleted and i have broken boot to my own OS.
- pendrive i want to recover have about 100 gb storage so I don't want to throw it to trash
- gnome parted shows random errors on trying to change something ( similar to gparted but doesn't freeze )
- also tried on windows - after only plugging in all system freezes. Force restart required
- after a trick with connecting to power pendrive automatically have partition ( which vanishes after trying to format, then both gparted and gnome parted just crash without lags )

what I've done to have this trouble? :
I'm not sure but it may be incomplete format or magnet ( as I think magnet can react with HDD only, so why USB ? anyways it also could ).

Now i saw that it might be also crash on drive ROM

Edit:

Today i tried a ton of commands. All with i/o error. List of them:

```
Dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc
Fdisk /dev/sdc             (With no more commands, for restoring partition table)
```

I’m gonna try a few other but i think i’ll need to sit next to my PC for about a week or month for searching for them

I found a tool for m$ windows to change ROM of pendrive but windows partition on my PC is broken (simple bluescreen)

„Reformatting” with cat allows me only to create empty partition which i can modify and/or write files (no filesystem)

Comment: why is your question not about recovering the pendrive data?

Comment: because there was nothing important. but all pendrive crashed and data now isnt too much important

Comment: Anyways, I made a bigger backup on external HDD and all data is there, so why recover? Idk